# Google Analytics / E-commerce / Advanced tracking

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

In my shop, i have differente areas and pages for pushing products :

- Home page

  - block discount
  - block featured products
- Product page

  - block related products
  - block you may also like
- Category page with a product list

I want to know from wich page or area, a product is sold and get datas like this :

### Area-----------Number of product views (or click)---------Number of sales

block featured home---------------------------1000------------------------------------10

block related product (product page)-------1000------------------------------------12

### Detail for the block featured in home page :

### Name-----------Number of product views (or click)---------Number of sales

product 1---------------------------450---------------------------------------------------------------8

Product 2--------------------------330----------------------------------------------------------------2

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a product like Magento, this would be easy.  But the only way you can confirm what page visits were converted into sales would be something different.  Take a look at https://www.google.com/analytics/features/conversion-suite.html to see if this meets your needs.  there are plenty of options if it's just visitors by geography, but to track conversions you have to incorporate more.

Comment: You should still checkout GA Conversion Suite.  Anyway, products like prestashop usually have plugins available that you can add to the admin that does all of this for you.  here's a brief discussion regarding it http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/187592-google-analytics-goal-conversion-funnel/